# python3 subprocess output enclosed in b' \n'

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, subprocess

I am trying to use subprocess module in python3 to fetch output of shell command in MacOS.

command I am using:

```
read_key = ["binary", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(read_key, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Different output I got.

```
>>> proc.communicate()
(b'MY_EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING\n', b'')

>>> proc.communicate()[0]
b'MY_EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING\n'

>>> proc.communicate()[0].strip()
b'MY_EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING'
>>>
```

But I am trying to get "MY_EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING" into a variable (without quotes). Is there any proper usage of subprocess which will allow that?
Or should I be using truncate, grep  etc to get around this issue?

expectation:

```
print(output)
    >>>>  MY_EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING
```

Am I doing this wrong way?
Also help me with simplest, but detailed article on subprocess module which you have bookmarked :)

Comment: What you have is a *bytes* object. You'll need to decode it

Answer (score 1):

Your output was in `bytes` format, you can decode it into `utf-8`

```
proc.communicate()[0].strip().decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `subprocess.Popen` treats the output streams as binary (so you get `bytes`, hence `b'...'`). (The subprocess could print out e.g. an image, which is binary data, and you wouldn't want that to be mangled.)

You can add the `encoding` parameter to have `subprocess.Popen` decode everything for you:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    read_key,
    shell=False,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    encoding="utf-8",
)
```

UTF-8 is generally a safe default unless you know better about your subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @AKH and AnhPC03

I am using below code now:

```
read_key = ["binary", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(read_key, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
output = proc.communicate()[0].strip()
print(output)
MY_EXPECTED_OUTPUT_STRING
```